# How to add directories to the Library search paths for autoconf

Tags: c, libraries, gettext, autotools, autoconf

I'm just getting started with autotools, and have followed A. Duret-Lutz's tutorial closely to get a working C hello world that uses GNU gettext.

The AM_CFLAGS and AM_LDFLAGS are set appropriately in the Makefile.am, and the code compiles and runs successfully.

The issue is that autoconf is not searching in the directories that AM_CFLAGS and AM_LDFLAGS is telling the compiler to search, and as a result not defining the HAVE_GETTEXT_H, HAVE_LIBINTL, etc. macros in the config.h.

How can I get the configure.ac to supplement the library and include directories it searches when using AC_CHECK_LIB and AC_CHECK_HEADERS?

Comment: Can you provide an example? Ordinarily, a user would use something like `./configure CFLAGS=-I/path/to/gettext/include LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/gettext/lib` for nonstandard library locations, and those would be used by the `AC_CHECK_HEADERS` and `AC_CHECK_LIB` macros if I recall correctly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10210401/539810) for example.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I'm realizing that passing environment variables to configure might be the best way to do this, but I was hoping for a way to add those nonstandard library locations in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I misread the original question but since nothing in my other answer is incorrect per se I'll add another answer.

In order to use custom paths in `AC_CHECK_HEADER` and `AC_CHECK_LIBS` one has to (temporarily) set `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` accordingly:

```
CFLAGS_backup="${CFLAGS}"
LDFLAGS_backup="${LDFLAGS}"
CFLAGS="-I/path/to/an/additional/include/ ${CFLAGS}"
LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/the/lib/ ${LDFLAGS}"

AC_CHECK_HEADER(...)
AC_CHECK_LIB(...)

## reset CFLAGS and LDFLAGS
CFLAGS="${CFLAGS_backup}"
LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS_backup}"
```

Within `AC_CHECK_*` you'd typically set `GETTEXT_CFLAGS` or `LIBINTL_LIBS` as variables and export them for use in automake per `AC_SUBST([GETTEXT_CFLAGS])` and `AC_SUBST([LIBINTL_LIBS])` respectively.

Unfortunately, you cannot access `AM_CFLAGS` or `AM_LDFLAGS` in configure.ac.

Now in `Makefile.am` you can use

```
AM_CFLAGS = $(GETTEXT_CFLAGS) <other stuff>
AM_LDFLAGS = $(GETTEXT_LIBS) <other stuff>
```

For convenience, typically, you'd expose a parameter to the user as well, either via `AC_ARG_WITH` or `AC_ARG_VAR`, so they can use `--with-gettext` or `LIBINTL_LIBS=...` along with the configure command.

Seeing as autoconf is really only m4 you could wrap the above in a macro yourself.  And seeing as we talk about gettext here, there is already such a thing: `AM_GNU_GETTEXT`, an m4 macro that you could use in your configure.ac after you called `gettextize`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `AC_CHECK_HEADER`, use `AC_CHECK_HEADERS`, that defines tokens of the form `HAVE_<HEADER>_H`.  The singular form expects you to define things yourself using the `ACTION-IF-FOUND` (2nd argument).

For `AC_CHECK_LIB` there is no such comfort, you must use the `ACTION-IF-FOUND` (3rd argument) and `AC_DEFINE` whatever is needed.

Additionally there will be shell variables `ac_cv_header_<HEADER>_h` and `ac_cv_lib_<LIBRARY>_<FUNCTION>` set.